# Images not showing when rendering PDF with twig in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, mpdf, symfony-3.4

When generating a PDF using mPDF (containing images), no images will show. The text displays just fine. For some reason it does add several blank pages to the PDF. Even though it has a footer text set for every page, these are still blank.

Tried to enable `$mPdf->showImageErrors`, this does not give any errors, also tried to search the error log. There are no errors thrown. Tried to catch any `MpdfException`. But none are thrown.

{twig tempalte}

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-size: 10px;
            line-height: 14px;
        }

        thead {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        table {
            margin: 15px 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        td {
            width: 165px;
        }

        tr {
            margin: 10px 0;
        }

        td table {
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        th {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }

        .row {
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-right: -15px;
            margin-left: -15px;
        }

        .full-table td {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
        <table class="full-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Screenshot</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{ asset('/images/path/to-image.png') }}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="full-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Screenshot</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{ asset('/images/path/to-second-image.png') }}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```php
$mPdf = new Mpdf();
$template = {twig template}
$filePath = '{var/location}';

$mPdf->watermarkImageAlpha = 1;
$mPdf->watermark_size = 'D';
$mPdf->watermark_pos = [107, 0];
$mPdf->showWatermarkImage = true;
$mPdf->watermarkImgBehind = true;

$mPdf->WriteHTML($template);
$mPdf->Output($filePath, Destination::FILE);
```

Expected for it to display images and background image, none are showing.

Comment: I would imagine that the `asset` twig function produces the paths for web, however, Mpdf doesn't know or care about paths for the web and only cares about paths that mean something in the filesystem. Just because Mpdf uses HTML as it's language to describe pdf contents, doesn't mean it employs a web browser to actually load those... meaning, you probably have to find/write a function different from `asset` to get the correct path to your images.

Comment: And it's easy enough to find out for sure whether or not that is the case. Replace one of those instances with the full path to the image and see if it works (it probably will).

Comment: also, I'm pretty sure Mpdf doesn't understand twig templates. you have to render it into "pure" html.

Comment: @Jakumi I did render them prior to passing it to mpdf. But it seems that `asset` does not work. When I changed it to full path it worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

@Jakumi and @Dave were right. Tried full paths and that seemed to work just fine. The examples I saw online also used relative paths from the the template to the images, figured that this would work as well.

**Fix: use full paths.**

Answer (score -1):

Need to use absolute_url and asset in twig.

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('invitation/logo_without_border.png', 'images')) }}" width="250px" height="70px">
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).